# No Simulators showing up under my Watchkit target

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, watchkit, apple-watch

My WatchKit target application isn't displaying any simulators, I'm using Xcode Version 6.2 (6C107a): https://i.stack.imgur.com/h02Px.png

[image: No Simulators showing up under my Watchkit target]

Comment: I think I figured out your issue - check out my answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29014349/1103584

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are other strange things about that scheme that you're displaying there. The WatchKit Extension would not normally appear there, nor should any of those CocoaPods. (I am assuming that the ThemoDiemExtension is the WatchKit Extension. If it is some other kind of Extension, perhaps it might be intended to appear there?)

Try selecting "New Scheme..." at the bottom of that menu, and create a new clean Scheme that includes your app and your watchKit App. You may also want to select "Manage Schemes..." and see if you can see anything clearly wrong with the current one.

I presume you have already tried the "More simulators..." option under the "Mickey's iPhone (no paired Apple Watch)"?

Comment: Thanks, adding the WatchKit Extension as a new schema the simulators showed up.  However, now when I run it I get a "running (null)..":
http://www.gfycat.com/AstonishingUnhealthyApe

Comment: It's the WatchKit app that you need there, not the extension. The extension code will run as a result,  and you'll see the extension code running, but the target you launch is the one with the UI.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your "app group" entitlements are not setup properly.  It's easy to fix:

1.) Delete your current watchkit app scheme.
2.) Open your project settings.  Open your main app target and go to the "capabilities" tab.

[image]

3.) Scroll down to the "App Groups" section and look at the "steps" section.  There should be 3 check boxes.  If anything is wrong there will be little X's next to the "steps" and a "Fix Issue" button.  Click that button.
4.) Do the same thing for your "WatchKit Extension" target.
5.) Create a new scheme for the watchkit app and simulators will show up and the app will load properly.

The attached screenshot will show you what it should look like when it's all working.